# Stop a wx.Control from losing focus on arrow key press?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

A pretty minimal example:

```
import wx

class Control(wx.Control):
    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        
        wx.Control.__init__(self, parent)
       
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.OnKey)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKey)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKey)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnMouseClick)
        
    def OnKey(self, event):
        print("key pressed")
        event.Skip()

    def OnMouseClick(self, event):
        self.SetFocus()
        print("has focus")
        event.Skip()
        
class Frame(wx.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        radio = wx.RadioButton(panel, label="Radio button")
        button = wx.Button(panel, label="Button")
        control = Control(panel)
        
        sizer.Add(radio, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(button, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(control, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        
        self.Show()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

By clicking on the control, sets the focus to control. However, even though binding key presses to a function `OnKey`, an arrow key press changes focus to another button/widget.

Is there a method similar to `AcceptsFocusFromKeyboard(self)`:

> Description: Can this window be given focus by keyboard navigation? if not, the only way to give it focus (provided it accepts it at all) is to click it.

Except, a method where my control doesn't lose focus from keyboard navigation?

Answer (score 0):

Both of you event handlers are missing the call to:

```
event.Skip()
```

Those events are non-wxCommandEvents and in order for them to work properly, OS has to perform whatever needs to be performed. That's what Skip() is for. Otherwise the event will be eaten by the control.

Please check the documentation for that method, add it and see if that fixes the issue.

Also, out of curiosity, what do you expect to happen when the user presses the arrow key?

If you want the focus to stay when the arrow key is pressed, try to filter the event by event.GetKeyCode() (check the docs for the proper function name) and don't call event.Skip() in this case.

If that doesn't work try to catch wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK event.

If even this doesn't work, override FilterEvent().

Also, the structure of you GUI is very weird. Try to get the RAD tool (wxGlade, wxSmith, etc), build it there and look at the result. Or check the demo folder in wxPython distribution (available as a different download) to see how to make the normal layout in wxPython.

It is also possible that by fixing the GUI you will fix the arrow key issue.

Try this code instead:

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        radio = wx.RadioButton(panel, label="Radio button")
        button = wx.Button(panel, label="Button")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.OnChar)
        radio.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKeyDown)
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKeyDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnMouseClick)

        sizer.Add(radio, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(button, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(control, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.Show()

    def OnKeyDown(self, event):
        print("key pressed")
        if not event.GetKeyPress() == wx.WXK_LEFT_ARROW: # Check the function name. I'm writing from memory
            event.Skip()

    def OnChar(self, event):
        print("Character key pressed on the panel")
        event.Skip()

    def OnMouseClick(self, event):
        self.SetFocus()
        print("has focus")
        event.Skip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You should get the idea. Call event.Skip() only if the key pressed is not an arrow key.

Comment: sorry I did test event.Skip() but I left it out of the example by accident. I want it to stay focused on the control, where the arrow key can change the state  of the control. For example, like a listctrl, the arrow keys can change the selection in the list instead of losing focus from the listctrl.

Comment: thanks, I will try the suggestions you have made. If you don't mind me asking, what about the code (not referring to things like spacing or naming convention) which seemed wrong/weird to you? I have seen many code examples from various tutorials which are constructed this way. (though I will check more code samples)

Comment: @Blackboard, sample code based on yours added. Make sure you check the docs for proper function name in the wxKeyEvent to get the key code. Also, I would use 2 different handlers for evt_key_down and evt_char. They are for 2 different events and it will interfere with one another.